# What's the recommended way of setting the SelectedItem of a Telerik RadAutoCompleteBox programmatically in UWP

Tags: uwp, telerik

`RadAutoCompleteBox`'s `SelectedItem` property [has a private setter](https://github.com/telerik/UI-For-UWP/blob/4de0962db4be6f8d3c4575735434354d09c8fc1c/Controls/Input/Input.UWP/AutoCompleteBox/RadAutoCompleteBox.cs#L747). What's the reason and how can I set the `SelectedItem` in a reliable way? Say I want to load a form containing user data from the database, how can I select the item that's specified in the database?

I searched the [official documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radautocompletebox/autocompletebox-overview) and couldn't find anything related to that there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **AutoCompleteBox** you set the `Text` property instead of the `SelectedItem`. This is because ultimately the value of the control's selection is a string.

For example, instead of doing something like:

```
acb.SelectedItem = myItem;
```

do this:

```
acb.Text = myItem.StringProperty;
```

If you need business object based selection instead of Text, ComboBox is a more appropriate control.